# Update a specific property of an object attribute in a Wordpress Gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a custom Gutenberg block with an attribute:

```
valuesObj: {
    type: 'object',
    default: {},
}
```

I want to update a specific property within that object when an input is changed. So I have created a function that gets called from `onChange` on the component:

```
<TextInput
    value={ valuesObj[index] }
    onChange={ (value) => this.onChangeValue(value, index) }
/>
```

This is the function that gets called:

```
onChangeValue(value, index) {
    var newValuesObj = this.props.attributes.valuesObj;

    newValuesObj[index] = value;

    this.props.setAttributes({ valuesObj: newValuesObj });
};
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to work at all. When I type in the `TextInput` nothing changes. When I save the post, nothing is saved for that attribute. I know the function is being called correctly and is passing the correct `value` and `index` (I `console.log` them). I've been scouring the Gutenberg documentation, but it doesn't seem to mention anything about this.

Not sure what I am missing/doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `onChangeURL` , but your method is called `onChangeValue`.

I'm not sure where the value of `index` is coming from but try to create a new object in your `onChangeValue` and set this new object for your attribute.

Try changing your `onChangeValue` to something like:

```
onChangeValue(value, index) {
    var newValuesObj = {};
    newValuesObj[index] = value;
    this.props.setAttributes({ valuesObj: newValuesObj });
  }
```

Comment: Whoops. That was a copy paste error from my desperate attempts to get this all working. Even with the correct method name, it still does not work. (I've also updated the question).

Comment: This helped point me in the right direction. It worked, except that all other props in the object were overwritten. I solved that by cloning the object (`var newValuesObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.attributes.valuesObj));`), then making my change. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're doing here, I believe the spread operator is a more common and more succinct way of accomplishing the same thing. Something like `setAttributes( { name: { ...object, [key]: value } } )`.