# Why doesn't a mutated array of objects save in Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to create a Gutenberg block where the user can enter several key-value pairs. These pairs are called `functions`, the key is called `name` and the value is `people`.

The following example with a hardcoded array works fine:

```
attributes: {
    functions: {
        type: 'array',
        default: [{name:'', people:''}]
    }
},

edit({attributes, setAttributes}) {
    function updateFunction(event) {
        setAttributes({functions: [{name:'Test function', people:'Jack'}]});
    }

    return (
        <table className='credits-table'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' placeholder="Function" value={attributes.functions[0].name} onChange={updateFunction} />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea rows='3' placeholder="Names" value={attributes.functions[0].people} onChange={updatePeople} />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    );
}
```

The attributes get updated and the new text is displayed inside of the input and textarea. This should however take the value of the function input to actually update of course, but it doesn't work this way:

```
function updateFunction(event) {
    let func = attributes.functions;
    func[0].name = "Jane";
    setAttributes({functions: func});
    console.log(attributes);
}
```

The output of the last line shows the expected result, but the text inputs don't update and even get cleared out again:

```
[{name: "Jane", people: ""}]
```

If I use `func[0].name = event.target.value`, the result of attributes is always `[{name: "e", people: ""}]`, no matter what letter I typed. `console.log(event.target.value);` does however log the letter I typed as expected.

So why doesn't this work? Is there some weird constraint on saving nested objects in Gutenberg I don't know about?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452438/update-a-specific-property-of-an-object-attribute-in-a-wordpress-gutenberg-block#comment99517264_56459084), I found a workaround, but there must be a better way, right?

```
function updateFunction(event) {
    var func = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(attributes.functions));
    func[0].name = event.target.value;
    setAttributes({functions: func});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JSON.parse and JSON.stringify. use the spread operator

```
function updateFunction(event) {
    var func = [...attributes.functions];
    func[0].name = event.target.value;
    setAttributes({functions: func});
}
```